# Variable in setOnClickListener cannot be resolved

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to make a stopwatch app for android using a `Chronometer` inside of a `Fragment`, but I'm getting errors on the `setOnClickListener` for some buttons.

It's the variables inside of parentheses "()" fx. (`mStartListener`), I get the error `mStartListener cannot be resolved to a variable`.

please help me, I really wanna get into android developing. Thank you

Here's the code

```
b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.start);
b.setOnClickListener(mStartListener); //--- error
b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.stop);
b.setOnClickListener(mStopListener); //--- error
b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.reset);
b.setOnClickListener(mResetListener); //--- error
```

Full Code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class StopWatchFragment extends Fragment {

    Chronometer mChronometer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stopwatch, container, false);

        Button b;
        mChronometer = (Chronometer) getView().findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        // Watch for button clicks.
        b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.start);
        b.setOnClickListener(mStartListener); //--- error
        b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.stop);
        b.setOnClickListener(mStopListener); //--- error
        b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.reset);
        b.setOnClickListener(mResetListener); //--- error


        return view;


    View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.stop();
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move where you declare each Listener to be class variables:

```
public class StopWatchFragment extends Fragment {

    Chronometer mChronometer;
    View.OnClickListener mStartListener;
    ...
```

**Or** just declare your listeners *before* you try to use them:

```
Button b;
mChronometer = (Chronometer) getView().findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mChronometer.start();
    }
};
...

// Watch for button clicks.
b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.start);
b.setOnClickListener(mStartListener); //--- no more error
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked, well i'm not getting any errors, but now my apps Force closes when i launch the fragment.

Comment: You're welcome. Try your best to solve the Force Close issue, if you can't please post a new question that includes the LogCat errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining and initializing the `mStopListener` inside the `onCreateView` method, **AFTER** you try to set them as the OnClickListener.

You should either move them to the start of your method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stopwatch, container, false);
   View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.stop();
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    };
    Button b;
    mChronometer = (Chronometer) getView().findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    // Watch for button clicks.
    b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.start);
    b.setOnClickListener(mStartListener); //--- error
    b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.stop);
    b.setOnClickListener(mStopListener); //--- error
    b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.reset);
    b.setOnClickListener(mResetListener); //--- error

    return view;



}
```

**Or,** put them outside your method as global variables.